# How to connect to internet from Ubuntu which is installed in a virtual machine using VMWare Workstation?

Tags: internet, virtual-machine, internet-connection, ubuntu-9.04, vmware-workstation

I have installed Ubuntu 9.04 on a virtual machine using VMWare Workstation. I have Windows 7 as my host OS.

I want to connect to internet from Ubuntu. Can anyone please gives steps for connecting to internet through guest OS?

Answer (score 29):

My solution was to delete and readd the network interface:

1. Shutdown your VM
2. Go to "Edit Virtual Machine Settings" and remove your network adapter
3. Boot your VM and turn it off
4. Open the .vmx file with your editor and delete all lines which start with "ethernet0"
5. Boot your VM and turn it off
6. Go to "Edit Virtual Machine Settings" and add a new network adapter
7. Boot your VM and open a terminal
8. Execute `ip link`. The output shows all the interfaces like this:

   ```
   1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
       link/ether 00:0c:29:a5:cd:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   ```
9. Find your interface (`ens33` in my case) and set it to up:

   ```
   sudo ip link set ens33 up
   ```
10. Let your interface search an IP Address:

    ```
    sudo dhclient ens33 -v
    ```

Worked with Windows 10 Host, Ubuntu 19.10 Guest and VMware Workstation 15 Player.

Comment: This works perfectly on linux host / ubuntu 18.04 too.

Comment: This also worked on windows 10 Host, Ubuntu 20.04 Guest and VMware Workstation 15 Player

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly!

Comment: The above instruction also helps me to get the interface up and obtain an IP. But after a reboot, the interface went down again

Comment: this works great! however, the steps after `ip link` should be repeated after each reboot...
there is no way to make this works ever after reboots?

Comment: Epic! Thanks a lot. The 2 commands at the end were essential to my case

Comment: Only steps 8 and 10 were needed in my case

Answer (score 8):

In your VMWare, go to **Edit>Virtual Network** Edits and create an add a new Network of type **NAT**.

Now, on your host goto **Control Panel > Network & Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings** and look for your current connection that has internet access.

Right-click the network connection and go under **Sharing**. Allow the sharing and choose the NAT Network from the drop-down.

Now, on VMWare, go to the settings of Virtual Machine. Under Network, choose Custom Network and select the same NAT connection. Now, reconnect to check if the connection is established.

Reference [Video]: [How to setup Internet Connection for Virtual Machines in VMWare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2j3nyl4muQ)

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled a network adaptor in the VM settings? NAT is the simplest option but bridged mode just as easy to set up if you have a DHCP server running on the network.

Is the network running in the guest? Do you have an IP address? If not:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

If you have an IP address in the guest it could the firewall on the host is causing the problem.

Comment: I get an error:
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking

Comment: In my case the issue was on the avast firewall which I had to switch it to "private" network instead of "public.

Answer (score 1):

Workstation sets up bridge network VMnet0 for Bridge Networking for the guests. Bridged networking connects a virtual machine to a network by using the network adaptor on the host system. 
You can enable it by right click on your Ubuntu Virtual Machine or `VM>Settings`
click on Network Adaptor and select Bridged, restart the guest if needed.

Comment: No, restarting doesn't do anything.

Comment: The bridged option should work, I've done the same thing with many Virtual Machines and they've worked fine. Have you checked the state of the network adapter within Ubuntu? Try something like "ip link" and check the state of your ethernet adapter, it'll probably be something along the lines of "enp---", check if the state is UP or DOWN. If its down, do a "sudo ip link set up xxx" where xxx is the adapter name. And then pull a "sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd", and give it a little time and see if anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

- Select Bridged on VMvare
- Install "VMware Bridge Protocol" to wireless adapters settings on PC.
- Restart VMware

Answer (score 0):

So I am running Ubuntu version 22 on VM Workstation 16 Player running NAT network adapter that kept on dropping, and would need to  constantly do @bb1950328's answer above to get it to run again but then I entered `sudo dhclient ens33` into the command line and it would be able to reconnect automatically. When the VM later refroze I needed to reenter `sudo dhclient ens33` but it reconnected right away.
Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the top answer?

Comment: Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help].